# OpenOffice Calc: reduce file size when saving as Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc

I'm working on a spreadsheet together with another person, sending new versions forth and back by email. It contains nothing fancy. While he uses Windows I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. The first version he sent was only 30 k. When I opened it in LibreOffice 3.5.7.2 (current Ubuntu version of OpenOffice) and just saved it again (still using the Excel format) it was 2.6 MB! After my edits it was 5 MB large which is not acceptable.

What `file` has to say about the original Microsoft Office file is: `Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 6.2, ... Name of Creating Application: Microsoft Excel, ... Security: 0`

After saving as Excel from LibreOffice, `file` says almost the same. Differences are: Version 1.0 instead 6.2, Code page: -535 instead 1252, Revision Number: 1 (not present in original file), Name of Creating Application and Security: no longer there.

Is there a way to reduce the file size?

Comment: ...and what does `file` tell you about the 5MB version? And are you saving as Excel (from LibreOffice), or in its native format? (And as an aside: f there's really nothing fancy in the spreadsheet, then: do you know the Google Drive spreadsheet functions? Nice collaboration, but not an answer to your question of course.)

Comment: I'm saving, not saving as, so LibreOffice keeps the file format and `file` says almost the same. Differences are: Version 1.0 instead 6.2, Code page: -535 instead 1252, Revision Number: 1 (not present in original file), Name of Creating Application and Security: no longer there.

Comment: Any chance LibreOffice formats all cells, and then basically creates the maximum sheet size? Not sure how to easily check that, but *if* it happens then it *might* be related to fonts in the Excel file that your Ubuntu does not have, which might somehow trigger some formatting of empty cells as well? So: any strange font used in the Excel file? And does the size decrease if you remove all formatting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the problem. There were 4 x 65536 (mainly unused) rows with a custom row height. I selected all unused rows, invoked Format > Row > Optimal Height and pressed OK. This shrinked the file from 5 MB to 10 k.

For discovering this I saved the file as .xlsx (Excel 2007/2010 XML or as OfficeOpen XML Spreadsheet, makes no difference). This is a zip format containing xml files. I unzipped it and found huge files like `xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml`. I formatted one of them using `xmllint --format` and found 65536 lines looking like `<row collapsed="false" customFormat="false" customHeight="true" hidden="false" ht="12.8" outlineLevel="0" r="65536"/>`.

Comment: Nice. And just curious: whenever saved in the "real" Excel, does the problem come back?

Comment: yes it does, at least with Excel 2013 which I have access to. I verified this with a minimal spreadsheet where I didn't even change any formatting!

Comment: to select unused rows, use Ctrl+Shift+ArrowDown then ArrowLeft, then  invoked Format > Row > Optimal Height and pressed OK. Thanks. It's save my day.

Answer (score 0):

If really nothing special in your file, are you sure not being adding some objects like pictures or other documents embedded in it ? I'm editing calc files with lots of data for a while, and always keep understandable size (using LibreOffice 4.x).

Some other ideas:
- zip/gzip the file before sending may save a lot
- if issue is mailbox usage, you may use other file sharing services.

Comment: Are you saving as Excel, like in the question? Opening the Excel and then saving right away already increases the size from 30k to 2.6MB. There shouldn't be any additional objects in the spreadsheet then.